# On some special spanning trees of grid graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, spanning-tree

I would like to know if there are existing results on the following objects:

> spanning trees of a grid graph, **with no corridor**

where a **corridor** is a vertex having exactly two neighbors, on opposite sides.

Here is a picture of a spanning tree with corridors in red:

[image: spanning tree with corridors in red]

I would be interested in counting and random generation. Is there some variant of the classical methods for spanning trees that would work for them?

I am motivated by some representation-theoretic setting where a corridor allows to factorise the situation.

The similar problem for planar binary trees is much simpler (see [Oeis sequence A5554](https://oeis.org/A005554)).

Comment: Wired spanning trees can be generated by Wilson's algorithm via loop erased random walk. In your situation, my guess would be generating via a loop erased walk where we alternately take (random )steps in $X$ and $Y$ co-ordinate? It needs to be checked though!

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that and it seems that this indeed gives spanning trees with much less corridors. But still there remains some.

Comment: Would it be of interest to count and uniformly sample these structures on 15-by-15 grids? This should be quite feasible using the [ZDD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-suppressed_decision_diagram) data structure. I could explain the details in an answer.

Comment: Well, one can certainly wonder about the asymptotic growth of the numbers of configurations on the n times n grid. I would guess the standard method would be to use the transfer matrix method and the powerful techniques of the australian school of combinatorial enumeration to guess asymptotics from the initial terms.