# Self-avoiding random walks that always turn

Tags: pr.probability, discrete-geometry, random-walks

I am wondering if the statistics of self-avoiding random lattice-walks
on $\mathbb{Z}^2$
that turn left or right at each step (i.e., they cannot continue the
direction of the preceding step) have been studied in the literature.
In particular, might there may be a way to view these walks as walks without
the turn restriction, at a different scale?

I am particularly interested in probabilities of forming closed, simple polygons,
as illustrated below.
But my simulations suggest that the median length of such a path before it
gets stuck in a cul-de-sac (which occurs ~70% of the time) 
is robustly about $62$, which suggests that
there may be clear statistics here, more interesting
than what I was investigating.

<strike>(By "robustly" I mean that the variance is quite small, perhaps $<1$.)</strike>

---

[image: SawTurnPoly]

   

<sup>The longest closed polygon achieved in $10^4$-run simulations: $145, 189, 209$.</sup>

---

***Addendum***.
Stan Wagon is pursuing a fascinating related question
seeking a Hamiltonian cycle filling a 3D cube, under the same
*must-turn* restrictions
(which was the inspiration for my question):

---

[image]

---

***Update/Correction.*** 
Indeed the median number of steps to a cul-de-sac is robustly $62$,
but my claim about variance was an incorrect use of the term "variance."
What I meant is that random trials unerringly lead to $62$, but
the distribution is as below.

---

[image: SAHist]

          

<sup>The number of trials out of $10^5$ (vertical axis) that lead to
a cul-de-sac after $n$ steps (horizontal axis).</sup>

---

Comment: Isn't this a usual random walk URW at a slower pace, and tilted by 45 degrees? The only difference is that every path in URW is reached in two different ways (depending on whether you start vertically or horizontally in the "tilted" one). If you care about self-avoiding paths, this is probably not enough, but the classical literature should give some useful information.

Comment: URW = Uniform Random Walk.

Comment: This question is somehow in the same spirit as one comment made on [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/186126).

Comment: You may consider the turning edge self avoiding walk (TESAW) where you do not impose that the walk is vertex self avoiding. That walk has several nice properties: It never hits a cul-de-sac.
It can always get back (you can see this by "exploring from the other end" it also will not be able to hit a cul-de-sac).It is always self crossing: If you come back to a vertex twice you have to turn 90 degrees the other way and you will not cross yourself.It is a way to explore the =1 case of the Lorenz mirror model, which means that it returns to the origin to give you a polygon with probability 1.